# ECLIPSE: ClassNotFoundException for existing class at the project

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, classnotfoundexception, url-pattern

So I got this project's directory structure at Eclipse:

```
src
     br.com
        ...
     br.com.caelum
        ...
     br.com.caelum.agenda.servlet
        ...
     br.com.caelum.mvc.logica
        ...
     br.com.caelum.mvc.servlet
        ...
        ControllerServlet.java
     br.com.caelum.servlet
        ...
```

At my web.xml file I put this to map the `ControllerServlet.java` class:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletDeControle</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        br.com.caelum.mvc.servlet.ControllerServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletDeControle</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mvc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when I access the `/mvc` URL, it returns a `classNotFoundException`. Other classes at the same src folder seems to be working fine, except that I find myself unable to change their URL Patterns.

Why?

EDIT: This is the full error stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class br.com.caelum.mvc.servlet.ControllerServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.caelum.mvc.servlet.ControllerServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error stack trace?

Comment: How do you build the project? can you make sure that the class is exists in folder WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: How can I access this folder? The solution found on Google doesn't seem to apply here.